# ESP32 SerialBT wrong password from bluetooth terminal

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

I connected to my ESP32 via bluetooth and put the password test to move the servo into a certain position. However, it keeps telling me its the wrong password via the terminal

I've tried classifying all variables as a string and also tried to add a " test" to see if that would change the results.

```
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <ESP32Servo.h>
#include <BluetoothSerial.h>

#if !defined(CONFIG_BT_ENABLED) || !defined(CONFIG_BLUEDROID_ENABLED)
#error Bluetooth is not enabled! Please run `make menuconfig` to and enable it
#endif

BluetoothSerial SerialBT;
Servo myservo;
String password = "test";
String getinput = "";
const int lockPosition = 90;
const int unlockPosition = 180;

void setup() {
  myservo.attach(13);
  myservo.write(lockPosition);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SerialBT.begin("ESP32 Lock"); // Name of the device
  Serial.println("The device is ready to pair");
}

void loop() {
  
  if (SerialBT.available()) {
    
    getinput = SerialBT.readStringUntil('\n');
    Serial.print("Received: ");
    Serial.println(getinput);

    if (getinput ==password) {
      
      SerialBT.println("Correct password, unlocking");
      myservo.write(unlockPosition);

    } else {
      
      myservo.write(lockPosition);
      SerialBT.println("Wrong Password");
      
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you see when `getInput` is printed? Alternatively, you can have a look at the `compareTo()` function for `String` objects, that might be more useful for debugging than the `==` operator. https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/compareto/

Comment: On the terminal i get "Received: test"  for the string compare I get -13 as a value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to occur via the userinput adding white spaces when being sent to the esp32. Solved it by using the `trim()` which removes any leading or trailing white spaces

```
yourvariable.trim();
```